# maven - limiting jars in manifest class-path

Tags: maven, classpath, manifest

Maven jar or war plugin allows one to specify  `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`   in the config. 
This will bring in all the dependency jar files into the class-path of the Manifest file. Suppose, if there are multiple dependency jar files,  How can we limit the number of jar files in the manifest class-path to few of them?

Comment: you want to exclude some jars from classpath or what?

Comment: Since the plugin updates the manifest file, I want to exclude certain jar files in the Manifest file.